# Copy Video From One location to another in Android

Tags: android

I m stuck with an issue that I want to copy/move a video from one location to another inside sdcard  in android.
does anybody know how to do that.?

Comment: see this http://exampledepot.com/egs/java.io/CopyFile.html

Answer (score 0):

```
private String CopyFile(String srcPath,String destPath)
{
    String videoFileName = VIDEO_FILE_PREFIX + mCurrentQuestion.getQuestionId() + VIDEO_FILE_SUFFIX ;
    File source= new File(srcPath);
    File destination= new File(destPath+"/"+videoFileName);
    source.renameTo(destination);


    return destPath+"/"+videoFileName;
}
```